# How can I change a column to plot a geom_bar() in Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I need to create a `selectInput` to select a column to plot a `geom_bar()`.

What I have been trying:

UI

```
      tabItems(
        tabItem("Coop_ativas", 
                fluidPage(h1("Cooperativas Brasileiras")),
                dataTableOutput("cooptable"), 
                box(plotOutput("correlation_plot"), widht = 8), 
                box(selectInput("features", "Características:", 
                                c("situacao_cadastral", "identificador_matriz_filial")), width = 4),
                box(plotOutput("regiao_plot"), widht = 8), 
                box(selectInput("regiao", "Região:", 
                                choices = list("Estado" = "uf", "Região" = "regiao"),
                                selected = "Estado"))
                ))
```

Server

```
 output$regiao_plot <- renderPlot({
      

      Coop_ativas %>% select(input$regiao[1]) %>% group_by(input$regiao[1]) %>% count() %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(10) %>% 
                      ggplot(aes(reorder(input$regiao[1], n), n), ) + 
                      geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue") +
                      geom_text(aes(label=n), vjust=0.5, hjust=-0.5, color="darkgrey", size=3) +
                      labs(title = "Cooperativas Ativas por Estado",
                           subtitle = "02/2020",
                           caption = "Fonte: RFB, tratado por OBSCOOP/USP",
                           #tag = "Figure 1",
                           x = "Estado",
                           y = "Quantidade") +
                      theme_minimal() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                                              plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                                              plot.caption = element_text(0.0)) +         
                      coord_flip() 
  
    
  })
```

Where is `input$regiao[1]` I want it to be `uf` or `regiao`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just found it.

Just need to transform the `input$regiao` into a `sym`.
And use it with `!!` .

```
  output$regiao_plot <- renderPlot({
      
      col <- sym(input$regiao)

      Coop_ativas %>% select(!! col) %>% group_by(!! col) %>% count() %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(10) %>% 
                      ggplot(aes(reorder(!! col, n), n), )
```